# How to execute a defined function after each function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-espresso, spoon

I am writing Espresso unit test code.
What I want to do is taking screenshot on every actions without specifying

```
takeSpoonScreenshot("")
```

This is my AndroidJUnit4 Testcode:

```
@Test
fun givenVideoDetail_whenChooseCurrentItem_thenShowCountLabel() {
    pickerPage {
        clickFirstVideoItem()
    }
    videoDetailPage {
        clickSelectCheckBox()
        assertCountLabel()
    }
}
```

and this is my VideoDetailPage.kt:

```
fun videoDetailPage(func: VideoDetailPage.() -> Unit) = VideoDetailPage.apply {
    assertFirstPage()
    func()
}

fun screenshotAfterAction(func: VideoDetailPage.() -> Unit) = VideoDetailPage.apply {
    func()
    takeSpoonScreenshot("")
}

object VideoDetailPage : BaseActions() {
    // Write 'How to test' here

    fun assertFirstPage() {
        resourceIsDisplayed(R.id.send_balloon_image)
        resourceIsDisplayed(R.id.media_detail_item_check_box)
        resourceIsDisplayed(R.id.video_editor_mute_btn)
    }

    fun clickFilterButton() = takeScreenshotAfterFunction {
        clickButton(R.id.image_editor_filter)
    }

    fun clickSelectCheckBox() {
        clickButton(R.id.media_detail_item_check_box)
    }

    fun assertFilterSelectionListIsOpen() {
        resourceIsDisplayed(R.id.media_filter_list)
    }

    fun assertCountLabel() {
        resourceIsDisplayed(R.id.media_editor_selected_count)
    }
}
```

See that I made `takeScreenshotAfterFunction`, but It is not proper because I should write `takeScreenshotAfterFunction` N times.

Comment: Check out any AOP framework (like AspectJ, or maybe android community have more common AOP tool), it seems to fit your needs

Comment: you can put it in @After